# Force update of a property binding in angular 2

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Consider the following component

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h3>Input with two decimals</h3>
      <input type="text" 
             [value]="formattedN" 
             (change)="nChanged($event.target.value)"/>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {

  private n: number = 0;
  private formattedN: string = "0.00"

  public nChanged(value) {
    this.n = parseFloat(value);
    this.formattedN = this.n.toFixed(2);
  }

}
```

The input should always be a number with two decimals. That is however not always the case. Try removing the last zero, the field is not changed to 0.00 which is what I want. I understand it doesn't work because the formattedN value is not updated, which means that the property binding is not updated, hence the value of the input is not updated.

Run the example in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Vyi4RKladslrdZslZQhm

Does anyone have a nice solution for this problem?

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6932

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer don't think it's related, as my input is a text input.

Comment: @SimonHawesome doesn't really help me give the input the behaviour that I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this ***[Answer](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ky5bMgAJXuzzOWrWPyMm?p=preview)***  what you're trying to accomplish????

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="formattedN" (change)="nChanged($event.target.value)"/>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {

  private n: number = 0;
  private formattedN: string = "0.00"

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  public nChanged(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.n = parseFloat(value);
    console.log(this.n);
    this.formattedN = this.n.toFixed(2)
    console.log(this.formattedN);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can this cause concurrency issues? How can I know if [(ngModel)] or (change) gets called first?

Comment: It probably cannot because ngModel is fired on the input event and the last input event will always be fired before the change event.

Comment: What do u mean by it? could you please brief me?

Comment: first `change` event gets fired, it alters the value of `formattedN`. As soon as value gets changed, `angular2` updates UI with `[(ngModel)] - two way binding` syntax.

Comment: Whenever the input is changed the input event fires, which is what ngModel uses to update the binding. `[(ngModel)]="formattedN"` is equivalent to `[value]="formattedN" (input)="formattedN=$event.target.value"`. When the input loses focus, the change event fires, at that point the model has already changed because of ngModel, therefore the value of formattedN changes, which causes the property binding to be updated with ngModel.

Comment: oh great explanation +1 for it.